# Are there any free security audit tool for SharePoint?

Tags: security

Are there any codeplex or 3rd party free tool for security tool? I need to run this on several sites and I dont have ample time to create a powershell script for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The [SharePoint Admin Toolkit](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508851%28office.12%29.aspx) has some nice permissions reporting in to too, like checking effective permissions.  Very useful.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Sushi - http://www.codeplex.com/sushi
has security reporting. Details here -
http://sushi.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Security%20Reports

Answer (score 1):

Not clear if you are after something for MOSS 2007 or SharePoint 2010 but have a look at this site and the PowerShell script:

http://geekswithblogs.net/bjackett/archive/2009/04/24/the-power-of-powershell-and-sharepoint-enumerating-sharepoint-permissions-and.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tool, only issue is it will run on one site at a time.

https://sppermissionanalyzer.codeplex.com/

Comment: Anuj,
I tried using your tool, but it's saying: "Site Collection administrator rights are required to run this utility on a site". But I am a Site Collection administrator. Please advice what can be a problem.